# Restore access to a Google Workspace Marketplace app listing after the Google account of the owner was deleted

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We published an app in the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace). It is used by about 50k users.

We lost access to the app listing because the employee who set it up left our company and his Google account was deleted. His Google account was deleted more than 20 days ago and can therefore not be recovered anymore.

The deleted Google account was the only account that had access to the app listing. The app listing still exists but you get an error when you try to install the app.

Is there a way to claim access to the app or somehow recover the access? Is there a way to contact Google about this issue? I couldn't find any contact info or documentation about that.

If someone from Google reads this feel free to contact me at bruno@pexels.com.

Comment: You should contact [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en#:~:text=Sign%20in%20to%20your%20Google,Help%20window%2C%20click%20Contact%20support) to see if there is something that can be done in your specific case.

Comment: An admin should be able to add a new owner. Note that if the project has no owners it can be soft deleted which can be recovered by an admin but it will be eventually deleted permanently otherwise.